# Are signed and unsigned int always binary identical when value is in positive range of signed int?

Tags: c, types

***char*** type is used in the example, but question relates to any integer type.

Can I be sure that
`signed char foo = 127;`
will always be binary identical to
`unsigned char foo = 127;`
so that it's possible to use *signed* variant for raw byte representation if **MSB** not needed?

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to be sure of it? Anyway, C standard allows 3 different negative number representations - 1's complement, 2's complement and sign/magnitude. All these have positive numbers represented as unsigned versions

Comment: You might want to specify a particular version of C, because I'm pretty sure in the very old versions there was no guarantee of that.

Comment: I am pretty sure I remember a historical machine that had 9 bit bytes with 1's complement math and in C the unsigned char was 0 - 255 and the signed char was -255 - -0, +0 - 255. And those were NOT binary identical, because there was an extra bit in there.

Comment: Let's take C99 and GCC for example. It's just interesting to know how safe it is to use signed variant to represent raw binary data.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the C version, take a look to [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) where `-0` was different to `+0`

Comment: @DavidRanieri It does because I'm pretty sure either C99 or C11 made 8 bit, 2's complement math required.

Comment: @ZanLynx: None of C 1999, 2011, or 2018 made eight-bit two’s complement required.

Comment: @ZanLynx are you sure? I'm not able to find any reference to this (2s complement being mandatory) in the C99 standard, take a look to 6.2.6.2/2 and 7.8.2.1 annex 193 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: @DavidRanieri I guess I was wrong, but I found this: https://twitter.com/jfbastien/status/989242576598327296?lang=en so it is coming up in future.

Comment: @ZanLynx I hope so, relying on those stone age designs by now is ridiculous, good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bits representing the values are not necessarily identical if padding bits are present but are identical if there are no padding bits.

C 2018 6.2.6.2 2 says of signed integer types:

> Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type…

So the value bits in a signed integer type are the same as the value bits in the corresponding unsigned type. This leaves three more sets of bits to consider:

- The sign bit.
- Value bits that are in the unsigned type but not the signed type.
- Padding bits.

The sign bit must be zero, because this paragraph also says:

> … If the sign bit is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:…

Those “following ways” (sign-and-magnitude, one’s complement, two’s complement) all result in negative values if the value is not zero. Since we are told the represented value is positive, it is not negative, and so the sign bit must be zero. (We should note the question asserts the value is positive, thus excluding zero. With sign-and-magnitude or one’s complement, zero can be represented with a sign bit of one, and thus it could have different bits from an unsigned integer zero, which has all zero bits.)

Any value bits in that exist in the unsigned type but not the signed type must be zero, since the value is the same in both types.

That leaves the padding bits, and that is where the correspondence fails. The values of padding bits are not specified by the C standard and therefore may differ between signed and unsigned type or even between two instances of the same value in the same type. A specific C implementation may of course define its padding bits so that signed and unsigned types with the same value always have the same padding bits, and that the padding bits correspond between the signed and unsigned types. (We could imagine that the sign bit in the signed type corresponds to a padding bit in the unsigned type instead of to a value bit.)

C 1999 has the same wording.